# How to add edge with string similarity scores and find center of the graph in python networkX

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I am comparing the string similarities of a group of words. I came up with a list of pairs with good scores (similar pairs). I first need to merge the ones that have connectivities. For example `[(1,2),(2,4),(7,8)`] merges to [`(1,2,4),(7,8)`]. Then I want to find the best representative for each group. So I am thinking to find the representative who is kind of in the center of each group/cluster.

Can I do it with networkX? If each edge has a score to measure the nodes similarities, how to find the center of the graph? How to add the score to the edge? Is there example codes?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Are you asking how to add an attribute to an edge? Does this help? https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this problem, from what I understood it is that you're trying to achieve. It seems that you firstly want to find the connected components from the list of edges. There's a specific function in `networkX` for this.

Let's consider the following example:

```
l = [(1,2),(1,2),(1,4),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(7,8),(9,7),(1,2)]
```

Let's construct a network form the above list. For generalisation purposes I'm taking the weight into account. Where the weight will be the amount of times a given edge appears:

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

G = nx.Graph()
weighted_edges = [(*i,j) for i,j in Counter(l).items()]
# [(1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 1), (2, 4, 1), (2, 5, 1), (2, 6, 1), (7, 8, 1), (9, 7, 1)]
G.add_weighted_edges_from(weighted_edges)
```

Now we can obtain the connected components with [`nx.connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components):

```
cc = nx.connected_components(G)
print(list(cc))
# [{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}]
```

Given that we want to obtain a measure of how representative a node/edge is in a given component, one option could be to look at the `degree` of the nodes. Where:

> The node degree is the number of edges adjacent to the node

So what we can do is iterate over the connected components, and look for the node with the highest centrality. Here's one way:

```
degree_cen = G.degree()
out = []
while True:
    try:
        component = next(cc)
        component_cen = {k: degree_cen[k] for k in component}
        center_node = max(component_cen.items(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
        out.append({'component':component, 'center_node':center_node})
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Which yields:

```
print(out)
# [{'component': {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, 'center_node': 2}, 
#  {'component': {7, 8, 9}, 'center_node': 7}]
```